# How to inject mapRoles into an EKS aws-auth ConfigMap via Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I want to automate inserting the ARNs of specific roles into an EKS aws-auth ConfigMap, right after deploying the cluster. However, it seems that Terraform is recommending using kubectl instead.

I have tried the following method but I'm getting an error that the **data block is not expecting here**.

```
data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster_auth" {
  name = "my_cluster"
}
```

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = aws_eks_cluster.my_cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(aws_eks_cluster.my_cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster_auth.token
}
```

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth_configmap" {
  metadata {
    name      = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
data {
    mapRoles = <<YAML
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/MyRole
  username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
  groups:
    - system:bootstrappers
    - system:nodes
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/MyRole
  username: kubectl
  groups:
    - system:masters
YAML
  }
}
```

Comment: [the fine manual](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/config_map#example-usage) says `data = {`

Answer (score 0):

you can give the [aidanmelen/eks-auth/aws](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/aidanmelen/eks-auth/aws/latest) a try ;)

```
module "eks" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  # insert the 15 required variables here
}

module "eks_auth" {
  source = "aidanmelen/eks-auth/aws"
  eks    = module.eks

  map_roles = [
    {
      rolearn  = "arn:aws:iam::66666666666:role/role1"
      username = "role1"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    },
  ]

  map_users = [
    {
      userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::66666666666:user/user1"
      username = "user1"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    },
    {
      userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::66666666666:user/user2"
      username = "user2"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    },
  ]

  map_accounts = [
    "777777777777",
    "888888888888",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm using an authority module that I've created to help me and I added this module in the Terraform Registry.

You can use as:

```
# main.tf
module "eks-auth" {
  source                     = "cayohollanda/eks-auth/aws"
  version                    = "0.0.1-alpha"

  k8s_endpoint               = YOUR-K8S-ENDPOINT
  k8s_cluster_ca_certificate = YOUR-K8S-CA-CERTIFICATE
  k8s_token                  = YOUR-K8S-TOKEN
  mapRoles                   = YOUR-ROLES

}
```

And here is an example of mapRoles definition:

```
# terraform.tfvars
mapRoles = [
    {
      rolearn = "arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT-ID]:role/[NODES-ROLE-NAME]",
      username = "system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}"
      groups = ["system:bootstrappers", "system:nodes"]
    },
    {
      rolearn = "arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT-ID]:role/[ROLE-NAME]"
      username = "[USERNAME]"
      groups = ["[GROUPS]"]
    }
]
```

Please remember to add the NodeGroup Nodes Role in your mapRoles.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and created a working example of how to update the automatically created aws-auth config map for an existing EKS cluster using terraform:
https://github.com/jamiemo/k8s-eks-aws-auth-configmap

```
# 1. Find cluster based on tags
data "aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources" "cluster" {
  resource_type_filters = ["eks:cluster"]

  tag_filter {
    key    = "Environment"
    values = ["dev"]
  }

  tag_filter {
    key    = "Project"
    values = ["jamiemo"]
  }
}

# 2. Extract cluster name
locals {
  cluster_arn      = data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.cluster.resource_tag_mapping_list[0].resource_arn
  cluster_name     = regex("^arn:aws:eks:.+:\\d+:cluster\\/(.+)$", local.cluster_arn)[0] 
}

# 3. Create EKS data sources with cluster name
data "aws_eks_cluster" "eks" {
  name = local.cluster_name
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "eks" {
  name = local.cluster_name
}

# 4. Create kubernetes provider
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.eks.token
}

# 5. Create IAM role and policy e.g. codebuild
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["codebuild.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "service_role" {
  name               = "service-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
}

# 6. Create servicec role permissions
locals {
  new_role_yaml = <<-EOF
    - groups:
      - system:masters
      rolearn: ${aws_iam_role.service_role.arn}
      username: ${aws_iam_role.service_role.name}
    EOF
}

# 7. Get aws-auth config map data source
data "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth" {
  metadata {
    name = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
}

# 8. Update aws-auth configmap
resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth" {
  force = true

  metadata {
    name      = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  data = {
    # Convert to list, make distinict to remove duplicates, and convert to yaml as mapRoles is a yaml string.
    # replace() remove double quotes on "strings" in yaml output.
    # distinct() only apply the change once, not append every run.
    mapRoles = replace(yamlencode(distinct(concat(yamldecode(data.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth.data.mapRoles), yamldecode(local.new_role_yaml)))), "\"", "")
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = []
  }
}
```